# How to pass a python list to a C extension function and append some values?

Tags: python, python-c-extension

Say I have a python list:

```
l=[[1,2],[3,4]]
```

I want to pass it to the following C extension:

```
PyObject *acc(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
PyObject * l;
PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O", &l);
//l.append([5,6]
}
```

I just wonder how to modify the above function to achieve what I want to do in the comment line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Err, that would be [`PyList_Append()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/list.html#PyList_Append)...